# Memory error while saving product and customer has something in cart

Tags: admin, cart, magento-1.6

I'm currently facing a problem with my Magento 1.6 configured for multi-sites.

If a logged customer has something in his shopping cart, and, in the same time, I save a product in the admin, the customer will get blank page after 30 seconds and in my apache log, I get an "Allowed memory size" error.

If I make the same thing but the shopping cart of my customer is empty, there is no problem.

I can't find any error logged in exception.log or system.log, not even in apache log.

The only way to unlock the customer is to delete manually his session file on the server in root/var/session/.

I've already tried to push back my memory_limit parameter to 1024M, but still fails.

What can I do here ? I'm kinda lost for 1 day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally managed to find my problem by following the debugging instructions in :

https://blog.nexcess.net/2011/04/15/logging-database-queries-in-magento/

I've adjusted the slow queries time to 0.1 sec and finally get output in the log file. I've quickly found a pattern in the file and find where was my problem.

It was a module I've installed which failed and uses all the memory.

If you get a memory leak error and can't find to resolve by increasing memory limit, use this kind of debug, could be helpful.